# My site is not rendering properly in chrome, Could this happen if Bootstrap and a CSS3 Class conflicted?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am working on a new page, the domain is quite large and I have never encountered this problem. I have finished my page that shows very well in all internet browsers, except in Chrome, I have cleaned the cache and nothing fixes

Could it be my CSS?

Any experience and / or suggestion?

In the image on the left is EDGE on the right is Chrome

Comment: Seems like browser cache to me, but maybe you could show us your code

Comment: Please show us your website or a screenshot of your console in Chrome. We don't see the images neither...

Comment: Please  add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It  was conflicting attributes between a personal CSS3 Class and a bootstrap class, each browser would render differentely

Answer (score 0):

If you think your code is error-free and it is the caches you're having trouble with. Then try pressing `CTRL+F5` to reload the page. It works for me when the changes in the page are not being applied consistently.